# Why does KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s', KeyEvent.ALT_MASK) create an Alt-F4 keybinding?

Tags: java, keylistener, key-bindings, windowlistener

Running the following:

```
    KeyStroke ks1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s', KeyEvent.ALT_MASK);
    KeyStroke ks2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.ALT_MASK);
    KeyStroke ks3 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, KeyEvent.ALT_MASK);

    System.out.println(ks1);
    System.out.println(ks2);
    System.out.println(ks3);
```

Results in:

```
    alt pressed F4
    alt pressed S
    alt pressed F4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because:

- the `int` value for the `char` 's' is 115
- and the int value of `KeyEvent.VK_F4` is  *also* 115

meaning that `k1` and `k3` are functionally the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method getKeyStroke(char, int), thus the compiler widened your char 's' to an int and called getKeyStroke(int, int). The latter expects a virtual key code, not a unicode character.

Since (int) 's' widens to the int 115 wich coincidences with VK_F4, its doing exactly what you told it to do: Create a keybinding with VK_F4 and mask ALT.

Basically what happened is, you *wanted* to create a keybinding for char 's', but the compiler chose to create a keybinding for int 115. Its a simple mistake of assuming an overload that does not exist but a compatible, semantically different, overload being substituted by the compiler.

Comment: One aspect of the issue is that the VK values for the capital letters A-Z match their char/int values, so the problem is hidden for those characters.  I.e. using an uppercase 'S' would work properly, while a lowercase 's' does not.

Comment: @BenCole I wouldn't call that an "aspect", its still calling getKeyStroke(int, int). Only the values do happen to match the expectation. I would still consider code using getKeyStroke() in this way as faulty. Its no more correct than i.e. JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(' '); which also happens to function by coincidence like HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS.

Comment: As long as one is using uppercase chars, the code appears to "work properly" despite, as you say, being faulty.  It is not correct, no, but it does work, and especially in an IDE, one may not notice that getKeyStroke(char, int) doesn't exist.

Comment: @BenCole Yes, I agree completely, its easy to make the mistake unknowingly and the chance of it remaining undetected is high. But what is the special argument you are trying to make? If you are getting at that it could be designed better and safer, yes, of course it could be designed better. But it is what it is and it will remain so to maintain compatibility.

Comment: --  I'm not trying to make any argument at all!  I wanted to add this to StackOverflow as I ran into it and couldn't find any information about it.